# Update file properties - used utc time as input and value gets changed

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I use the SharePoint Action PatchFileItem ("Update file properties") and would like to set the time to a specific value.

Input: `2023-12-31T13:00:00.0000000Z`

Output: `2023-12-31T05:00:00Z`

[image: Power Automate Action - Update file properties]

Why does 13:00 suddenly become 05:00?

Am I on the wrong track? Am I stupid :D

Comment: The time you’re setting it to is UTC, is your site setup in another timezone? I’ve never used that operation but looks like it could be related to that.

Comment: Hi @Skin - Yes, I have configured a different time zone under Site Settings > Regional settings. Nevertheless, the data in SharePoint must be saved in UTC, otherwise how could it be converted dynamically? I have also selected the UTC offset +1, which also does not match this change.

Comment: Per my knowledge, the output is decided by regional settings in the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally stupid mistake on my part, after several checks of my settings in SharePoint etc. and much wasted time I discovered that a space was the culprit. When configuring the Power Automate Action, I must have accidentally inserted a space in there...

[image: Empty Space in Power Automate Action]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, the issue is indeed related to time zone settings: SharePoint stores date and time fields in UTC internally (as seen in [this thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Date-Times-in-Sharepoint-List-converting/td-p/969700)), but it displays them according to the regional settings configured for the site.
When you input a date-time value through Power Automate, if the regional settings of your SharePoint site are set to a time zone different from UTC, SharePoint may convert the input UTC time to the site's local time.

The discrepancy you are seeing (13:00 UTC becoming 05:00) should mean there is an automatic conversion happening based on a time zone setting that is 8 hours behind UTC:

```bash
Input Time (UTC)                 SharePoint Site Time Zone                        Displayed Time
    13:00 -------------------> | Site Time Zone GMT-8      | -------------------> 05:00
```

Even though you have set the UTC offset to +1, the conversion does not match this change, which indicates that the offset is not being respected in the way you expect.

So, double-check the site's regional settings to confirm the time zone, and make sure any user profiles interacting with the site also have the correct time zone settings.
Review the Power Automate action configuration to see if there is an option to specify the time zone context for the date-time value.

If the conversion is still not as expected, you might consider using an expression in Power Automate to format the date-time value correctly considering the time zone. For example, you could use an expression to add or subtract the necessary hours to align with your desired time zone ([`addHours`](https://manueltgomes.com/reference/powerautomate-function-reference/flow-addhours-function/)).

```
addHours('2023-12-31T13:00:00Z', -8)
```

That would subtract 8 hours from the UTC time, which should correct the automatic conversion if your SharePoint site is configured for a time zone that is GMT+1. See also [this thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/addHours-produces-different-date-times/td-p/500572) for illustration.

---

As suggested by [Utmost Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6901693/utmost-creator) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77727852/update-file-properties-used-utc-time-as-input-and-value-gets-changed/77733126?noredirect=1#comment137302261_77733126):

> I think `convertTimeZone` might also help to resolve this issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#convertTimeZone or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/power-platform/power-automate/converting-time-zone-power-automate - `convertTimeZone(timestamp: string, sourceTimeZone: string, destinationTimeZone: string, format?: string)`

True, the [`convertTimeZone` function in Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/power-platform/power-automate/converting-time-zone-power-automate) could help address the issue by converting the time from UTC to the desired time zone in a more controlled manner. The function allows you to specify the source and destination time zones explicitly, which should prevent unexpected shifts due to regional settings.

For instance:

```
convertTimeZone('2023-12-31T13:00:00Z', 'UTC', 'Central Europe Standard Time', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ')
```

That expression would convert the time from UTC to Central European Time (assuming that is the desired time zone), keeping the time component intact.
The format string `'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ'` at the end specifies that the output should be in a specific date-time format, which includes the time.

Comment: I think `convertTimeZone` might also help to resolve this issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#convertTimeZone or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/power-platform/power-automate/converting-time-zone-power-automate - `convertTimeZone(timestamp: string, sourceTimeZone: string, destinationTimeZone: string, format?: string)`

Comment: @UtmostCreator True, thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer to include an illustration of that.